# What are the options for open source workflow / groupware software fit my requirements?

Tags: workflow

In our company we use paper forms for our business. The form goes through multiple hands to get approval. In the process, different people may add content into the form.

We plan to use computer + software to replace the paper. I believe this a typical workflow / groupware application. At least, my experience with Lotus Notes matches. However, when I search online groupware seems all about project management, whereas workflow seems about creating some kind of flow chart like that of SW programming.

My requirement is simple, we want to be able to customize e-form and save it inside the system. Managers on different level sign in to the system and approve the form in sequence. Think of a travel expense reimbursement process.

I am looking for open source solution for this. Hopefully web based (Linux, Apache, PHP are preferred), mobile end support is a plus. Any suggestions?